# xamarin.android binding thorw 'does not implement inherited abstract member 'RecyclerView.Adapter.OnCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup, int)'

Tags: c#, binding, xamarin.android

I am binding the github project [ChatKit](https://github.com/stfalcon-studio/ChatKit.)

I do this xml

```
<attr name="managedType" path="/api/package[@name='com.stfalcon.chatkit.messages']/class[@name='MessagesListAdapter']/method[@name='onBindViewHolder']/parameter[1]">Android.Support.V7.Widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder</attr>
  <attr name="managedType" path="/api/package[@name='com.stfalcon.chatkit.messages']/class[@name='MessagesListAdapter']/method[@name='onBindViewHolder']/parameter[2]">int</attr>
```

but vs still throw the error for me:

```
1>D:\TempApps\ChatKitDebugBinding\ChatKitDebugBinding\obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Stfalcon.Chatkit.Messages.MessagesListAdapter.cs(10,23,10,42): error CS0534: 'MessagesListAdapter' does not implement inherited abstract member 'RecyclerView.Adapter.OnCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup, int)'
```

And there is any way to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to fix this is by partial classes. You can do this by creating a partial class of `MessagesListAdapter` with your **appropriate namespace**:

```
namespace Com.Your.Namespace
{
    partial class MessagesListAdapter
    {
    }
}
```

Next you can implement the overrides inside this partial class:

```
public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}

public override RecyclerView.ViewHolder OnCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Finally you can look through the [source code](https://github.com/stfalcon-studio/ChatKit/blob/master/chatkit/src/main/java/com/stfalcon/chatkit/messages/MessagesListAdapter.java) and use the newly generated binding classes to implement these methods in C#:

[`OnBindViewHolder`](https://github.com/stfalcon-studio/ChatKit/blob/master/chatkit/src/main/java/com/stfalcon/chatkit/messages/MessagesListAdapter.java#L104-L111)

[`OnCreateViewHolder`](https://github.com/stfalcon-studio/ChatKit/blob/master/chatkit/src/main/java/com/stfalcon/chatkit/messages/MessagesListAdapter.java#L98-L100)

Answer (score 0):

Check your generated source code. The method might actually be there, but with a virtual flag instead of an override flag. If so, you can fix it with managedOverride like this in metadata: you might need the ones you added in addtion to these.

```xml
<attr path="/api/package[@name='com.stfalcon.chatkit.messages']/class[@name='MessagesListAdapter']/method[@name='onCreateViewHolder']" name="managedOverride">override</attr>

<attr path="/api/package[@name='com.stfalcon.chatkit.messages']/class[@name='MessagesListAdapter']/method[@name='onBindViewHolder']" name="managedOverride">override</attr>
```